# C# to Excel Data Transfer Resulting In Rectangles

Tags: c#, excel, for-loop

I ran into a peculiar issue this morning while testing some Microsoft Word to Excel transfer scripting I had started the other day. For some reason, Microsoft Excel has taken to leaving small rectangular looking characters in every cell that had data inputted. These characters do disappear once I attempt to edit the cell but if the user has to F2 every cell to rid themselves of these tiny life plaguing boxes it makes my work practically useless as it aims to increase the efficiency of the worker and not have copy/paste functions be simpler. I haven't been able to find any other reference to my little boxes and have inserted a small screenshot for any clarification. The code is also attached.

```
  foreach (Word.Table tb in docs.Tables)
    {
        for (int row = 1; row <= tb.Rows.Count; row++)
        {
            rowCount++;
            for (int col = 1; col <= tb.Columns.Count; col++)
            {
                try
                {
                    var cell = tb.Cell(row, col);
                    try
                    {
                        object text = cell.Range.Text;
                        Console.WriteLine(text);
                        wks.Cells[rowCount, col].Value2 = text;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                // text now contains the content of the cell.
            }
        }
    }
```

I've found while debugging that as the values are read from Microsoft Word there seems to be "\r\a" added on to my strings. No idea where it's coming from.

Hopefully, this issue can be resolved sooner rather than later. Or I might have to ditch the project entirely.

[image: Image of Stupid Rectangles]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else ever encountering this issue. During the interop conversions from word tables to the console it retains the ascii code for newline perhaps or some other bit. Simply removing the last two characters from the string enabled me to remove the dreaded squares.

Simply put use.

```
text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 2);
```

Between the input and output.

Comment: Why not try trimming the string?

Comment: @IanKemp I could attempt trimming the string but at least in this example I've found the .Substring method works just as well. Perhaps if I run into similar issues in the future I may attempt trimming specific characters.

Comment: And what happens if the string is less than 2 characters?

Comment: @IanKemp Well if you read the original issue, the string won't have less than 2 characters. Even if the original input from word is completely blank during transfer the 2 characters that create the boxes from the original post still exist, as seen with the many cells in the above image having boxes in them and no other characters. It is possible for some instance that more characters may be added for some unforeseen reason and in that case trimming is definitely the way to go, but as stated .Substring works fine for this example.